# Pushing object to Array makes parameter empty

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to solve problem of merging two arrays of objects, so I wrote a pretty simple function

```
function mergeShowtimes(movies) {
    var existing_halls = [];

    return movies.reduce(function(acc, movie) {
        var movies_with_hallid,
            movies_seats;

        if (existing_halls.indexOf(movie.hallId) === -1) {
            movies_with_hallid = _.filter(movies, function(filter_movie) {
                return movie.hallId === filter_movie.hallId;
            });

            movies_seats = _.map(movies_with_hallid, 'seats');
            movie.seats = _.union.apply(this, movies_seats);
            acc.push(movie);
            existing_halls.push(movie.hallId);
        }

        return acc;
    }, []);
}
```

problem is, whenever I check the value of `movie` and `movie.seats`, field 'seats' in `movie` is empty, but `movie.seats` is not, for some reason

If I'll remove `acc.push(movie);` everything will start working as planned

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: What is that _ object ?

Comment: @EricMORAND that's Lodash

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful.

Comment: where is acc initialized?

Comment: @Ctznkane525: That's part of `Array.prototype.reduce`.  The second argument to `movies.reduce` is `[]`, which is the initial value of `acc`.  After that, it's given whatever was returned by the last iteration.